# cmake override compile definitions from command line

Tags: makefile, cmake, definition

I have a project with `cmake` and I want to set a compile definition that the user can override from command line every time the `make` command runs, and set it to whatever they want. I want this to be a string.

I tried to add

```
add_compile_definitions(USER_DEFINITION)
```

and run `make USER_DEFINITION="HELLO" VERBOSE=1`

But I see that the compiler ignores my setting as a string and it just defines it like a boolean.

```
arm-none-eabi-gcc -DUSER_DEFINITION
```

I tried to omit the `add_compile_definition` but I get `error: 'USER_DEFINITION' undeclared`

Is there any way I can do that in `cmake`?
I could use cmake arguments but I don't want to reconfigure cmake every time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since a variable in a Makefile is referred with `$(varname)` syntax, you may write

```
add_compile_definitions(USER_DEFINITION=$(USER_DEFINITION))
```

That way, building the project with

```
make USER_DEFINITION="HELLO"
```

will pass `-DUSER_DEFINITION=HELLO` option to the compiler.

Note, however:

1. This is **undocumented** feature. It could work in current CMake version and could break in the future versions.
2. Changing value of the variable does NOT **enforce** Make to **rebuild** the executable.
   That is, if you run `make USER_DEFINITION="HELLO"` and then `make USER_DEFINITION="GOODBAY"`, the second invocation won't rebuild the executable with the new macro value. You need to explicitly call `make clean` or `make <path-to-object-file>` for rebuild the executable.
3. This works only with Makefile-related generators (build systems). E.g. working for `Ninja` could require other reference to the variable.

Comment: It works, thanks! Needed some backslash. `make USER_DEFINITION=\\\"HELLO\\\"`